# Как запускать функцию при запуске Телеграм бота Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Делаю Телеграм бота на Python (Aiogram). Нужно при запуске бота запускать функцию, расположенную в другом файле. Вариант с `on_startup` функцией не подходит ибо при импорте данной функции получается `circular import`. Есть какие-либо способы реализовать эту задачу? Сейчас функция запускается с помощью команды `/start`

**bot.py**

```
import asyncio
import logging
import os

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from environs import Env


load_dotenv()

BOT_TOKEN = str(os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
ip = os.getenv("IP")

asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, loop=loop)

env = Env()
env.read_env()
ADMIN_ID = env.int("ADMIN_ID")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from handlers import dp
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp)
```

**handlers.py**

```
...
@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
@auth
async def main(message: Message, as_html=True):
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, " Бот запущен")
    ...
...
```

Comment: Может быть хоть код покажете?

Comment: @MyZik добавил код, правда, без понятия чем он тут поможет так как вопрос больше теоретический